# Avoiding acknowledgement of events from shared iCloud calendar on macOS Calendar?

Tags: macos, calendar, ical

Is there any way to avoid having to click OK for all events on calendars shared with me (to which I am not actually invited)? I tried checking "Ignore alerts" under the the shared calendar "Get Info" option, but this seems to have no effect? I have also selected None for Events in Preferences->Alerts.

Comment: The iOS equivalent is in settings under Shared Events as Show Changes. I don't know of a macOS equivalent.